# Change Index BLog to Directory Blog [Jekyll]

Tags: ruby, jekyll

How do I replace a blog list of index

example: `mysite.com` to `mysite.com/blog`

I have copied from the index and make myste.com/blog.html , but it does not work

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="home">

<div class="site-header-container {% if site.cover %}has-cover{% endif %}" {% if site.cover %}style="background-image: url({{ site.cover | prepend: site.baseurl }});"{% endif %}>
  <div class="scrim {% if site.cover %}has-cover{% endif %}">
    <header class="site-header">
      <h1 class="title">{{ site.title }}</h1>
      {% if site.subtitle %}<p class="subtitle">{{ site.subtitle }}</p>{% endif %}
    </header>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="post-list">
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
  <li>
    <h2>
      <a class="post-link" href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
    <section class="post-excerpt" itemprop="description">
      <p>{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}</p>
    </section>
    <section class="post-meta">
      <div class="post-date">{{ post.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</div>
      <div class="post-categories">
      {% if post.categories.size > 0 %}in {% for cat in post.categories %}
        {% if site.jekyll-archives %}
        <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/category/{{ cat }}">{{ cat | capitalize }}</a>{% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}
        {% else %}
        <span>{{ cat | capitalize }}</span>{% if forloop.last == false %}, {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}{% endif %}
      </div>
    </section>
  </li>
  {% if forloop.last == false %}
  <hr>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
  <p>
    {% if paginator.next_page %}
    <a class="newer-posts" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/page{{paginator.next_page}}">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    {% else %}
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    {% endif %}
    <span class="page-number">Page {{ paginator.page }} of {{ paginator.total_pages }}</span>
    {% if paginator.previous_page %}
      {% if paginator.page == 2 %}
      <a class="newer-posts" href="{% if site.baseurl %}{{ site.baseurl }}{% endif %}/">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      {% else %}
      <a class="newer-posts" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/page{{paginator.previous_page}}">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
        </span>
      </a>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
    </span>
    {% endif %}
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/posts">View All Posts by Category</a>
  </p>
</nav>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Suggest reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This should be a layout in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Open your config file, and set baseurl as /blog

```
baseurl: "/blog"
```

And use `prepend:site.baseurl` everywhere, just like you have used in above code

```
{{ site.baseurl }}/category/{{ cat }}
```